Correct way to handle Cors origin: Null
What is the correct way to handle a Origin header of Null? We are working on a chrome extension, and any ajax requests made from this extension have a origin of null (as might be expected). In order to allow this extension to communicate with an API, we'd need to update the CORS middleware to allow an origin of null, which after doing some searching sounds insecure.
What is best practice when handling the situation where the origin header is expected to be null?

Try adding this header with a real value by using chrome.declarativeNetRequest, see this example.
